# Webforms ajax call fails when trying to hit server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Jquery:

```
    $('.btn-block').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "ForgottenPassword.aspx/Test",
            success: function (data) { alert("success"); },
            error: function (data) { alert("fail"); }
        })
    });
```

Code behind:

```
<WebMethod>
    <ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False)>
    Friend Async Sub Test()
//stuff
End Sub
```

It just alerts fail every time I try to hit my server side code. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

I have put in a break point in my code, but it doesn't hit the breakpoint

Comment: can you please put your aspx.cs code here

Comment: If you `console.log(data);` in the error function and then inspect it, what does it say? Maybe there are hints on what is going wrong. HTTP status 404, 500, statusText?